# ¿Cuál es el animal con más nombres en castellano?

Tags: sustantivos, animales

[La iguana rayada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctenosaura_similis) (*Ctenosaura similis*) tiene por lo menos 19:

| Palabra | Regiones |
| --- | --- |
| garrobo<sup>1 4</sup> | `Mx:SE, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, CR` |
| gallina de palo<sup>1</sup> | `CR` |
| garmelio<sup>1</sup> | `CR Norte` |
| gueishpo<sup>1</sup> | `ES` |
| gueshpo<sup>1</sup> | `Gu, ES` |
| guespo<sup>0</sup> | `ES` |
| güembo<sup>1</sup> | `Hon norte-sur-este, ES este` |
| grencho<sup>0</sup> | `Hon [sur], ES` |
| groño <sup>0</sup> | `ES` |
| güirrío<sup>1</sup> | `ES` |
| güilla<sup>1</sup> | `Ni` |
| mapachagüe<sup>1</sup> | `Mx sureste` |
| iguana negra<sup>† 0 3 4</sup> |  |
| iguana negra de cola espinosa<sup>4 5</sup> |  |
| iguana espinosa<sup>6</sup> |  |
| iguana espinosa rayada<sup>0 2 4</sup> |  |
| iguana rayada<sup>7</sup> |  |
| tolok<sup>‡ 7 8 9</sup> |  |
| ctenosaurio<sup>6</sup> |  |

¿Hay algún animal que tenga más nombres comunes en castellano?

[image]

---

**Notas/Fuentes:**

<sup>†. También se llama así el [*Ctenosaura pectinata*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctenosaura_pectinata).</sup>
<sup>‡. También se llama así el [*Ctenosaura defensor*](https://www.naturalista.mx/taxa/35317-Ctenosaura-defensor) [2](https://www.ecured.cu/Iguana_de_cola_espinosa)</sup>

<sup>0. [termbank.com: black spiny-tailed iguana](https://termbank.com/en/spanish-english/iguana%20(iguana%20iguana))</sup>
<sup>1. [Diccionario de americanismos: garrobo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=garrobo)</sup>
<sup>2. [Sistema Integrado de Información Taxonómica. *«Ctenosaura similis (TSN 585835)»*](https://www.itis.gov/servlet/SingleRpt/SingleRpt?search_topic=TSN&search_value=585835#null)</sup>
<sup>3. [The IUCN Red List of Endangered Species](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/174480/0)</sup>
<sup>4. [Naturalista.mx](http://www.naturalista.mx/taxa/35303-Ctenosaura-similis)</sup> 
<sup>5. [EncicloVida.mx](http://enciclovida.mx/especies/8000549)</sup>
<sup>6. [El componente endémico de la herpetofauna hondureña en peligro crítico: priorización y estrategias de conservación](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262564468_El_componente_endemico_de_la_herpetofauna_hondurena_en_peligro_critico_priorizacion_y_estrategias_de_conservacion)</sup>
<sup>7. https://www.yucatan.travel/blog/el-tolok-importante-personaje-del-paisaje-yucateco/</sup>
<sup>8. http://seres19.blogspot.co.uk/2017/11/tolok-ctenosaura-similis.html</sup>
<sup>9. [*"Animals and the Maya in Southeast Mexico"*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/297647639_Animals_and_the_Maya_in_Southeast_Mexico_E_N_Anderson_Felix_Medina_Tzuc), E. N. Anderson Felix Medina Tzuc (*Journal of anthropological research*, Dec. 2006)</sup>

Comment: Si contamos localismos como diferentes nombres, probablemente el cerdo común sea uno de los animales con más denominaciones distintas.

Comment: Como dice @pgg66, probablemente sea cerdo. Tirando de DIRAE: cerdo, puerco, marrano, rungo, cuchí, gocho, tarasca, varraco, verraco, verrón, cuino, cocho, garrapo, currucho, gorrín, gorrino, frajenco, cochino, cochinillo, güirro, malandar, babirusa, gruñente, gurriato, tunco, sancho, chancho, guarín, trasca, cerdudo, etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Entre los que encontré yo antes de mi primer comentario y los que aportó @Rotten que yo no había encontrado en mi primera búsqueda, me he permitido elaborarte esta lista. Dependiendo de lo estrictos que queramos ser con la definición, podemos contar más o menos de estos términos.

> **1. [cerdo, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8KHKmOx)**
>
> De cerda, 'pelo grueso'.
>
> **1.** m. y f. Mamífero artiodáctilo del grupo de los suidos, de cuerpo grueso, cabeza y orejas grandes, hocico estrecho y patas cortas, que
>   se cría especialmente para aprovechar su cuerpo en la alimentación
>   humana. U. en m. ref. a la especie.

2. cerdudo ([3.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8KQf6Dy) En desuso)
3. chancho ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8Xnmkqe) América; [1.](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/chancho#Sustantivo_masculino) América del Sur, Costa Rica)
4. chanco (Quizá Ecuador, quizá Chile. Sólo he encontrado referencias literarias en [un antiguo diccionario hispano chileno](https://books.google.es/books?id=qrNEAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA14&lpg=RA1-PA14&dq=chanco%20cerdo&source=bl&ots=2rbxuthti2&sig=ee8e2-ERjAvQgJgEqMdj39zkwhk&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM0IanjKHbAhVFUBQKHet9CK0Q6AEIVjAM#v=onepage&q=chanco%20cerdo&f=false))
5. cochinillo ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9aQumWy) Hipónimo, como 'lechón')
6. cochino ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9aSHfhh))
7. cocho ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9aaMOoC), ¿quizá más común en México?)
8. cuchí ([2.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BY4lsmT) ¿quizá más común en Ecuador y/o Perú?)
9. cuino ([2.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bc6JRL6) Asturiano rural)
10. currucho ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BkME1VZ) Nicaragua rural)
11. cuto ([1.](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/cuto#Sustantivo_masculino) Extremadura, Navarra y Salamanca. Yo sólo lo conocía en Navarra. La RAE sólo recoge [sus acepciones latinoamericanas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BmySyRI%7CBn0VAWC), que son distintas)
12. frajenco ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=INmsZr2) Aragón)
13. garrapo ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IwXjlLF) Salamanca)
14. gocho ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JHgCWBY))
15. gorrino ([1., 2.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JMhi1lS))
16. gorrín ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JMfxj79))
17. gruñente ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JaUsfwx) germanía)
18. guarro ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JlEyE0Z%7CJlFyrV3))
19. guarín ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JkW2ri5) Un hipónimo bastante específico)
20. gurriato ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JtkpH7i%7CJtkvLDG) León, Salamanca y Zamora)
21. güirro ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JreyO2a) Parece el equivalente costarricense a 'guarín')
22. lechón ([1. ó 3.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N3A14KR))
23. malandar ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Nz15HiR) )
24. marrano ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OTsV0OJ%7COTslzYG))
25. puerco ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UaBS0qP))
26. rungo ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WqPTGa7) Un hipónimo salmantino)
27. sancho ([2.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XBNb6f1) Teruel)
28. seta ([4.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XQoSMnA) cerda)
29. seda
30. tarasca ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZBA6fCG%7CZBAZqvU) Sólo en femenino)
31. trasca ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aPDJOH2%7CaPJwCgi) Similar a 'tarasca')
32. tunco ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=auRDq9n%7CauSvnmp) El Salvador, Honduras y México)
33. varraco ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bOQrBo3) Como 'verraco')
34. verraco ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=beyYx9a))
35. verrón ([1.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bf79oUB))
36. coche ([36.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9ZO4sFe))
37. macho ([13.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NndQJAy) Cuba)

Comment: en donde le dicen tarasca a los cerdos ?  
apoco la bestia de santa marta fue un cerdote ?

Comment: @Mike: el enlace lo ha puesto pgg66: del DLE: **http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZBAZqvU: tarasca (2) Del lat. mediev. troia. 1. f. p. us. cerda (‖ mamífero).**   Observa que es una entrada diferente de **http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZBA6fCG tarasca (1)** De or. inc. 1. f. Figura de sierpe monstruosa, con una boca muy grande, que en algunas partes se saca durante la procesión del Corpus. 2. f. Persona o cosa temible por causar grandes daños y gastos o por su voracidad.
3. f. coloq. Mujer temible o denigrada por su agresividad, fealdad, desaseo o excesiva desvergüenza. 4. f. Chile y C. Rica. Boca grande.

Answer (score 4):

De momento, solo he encontrado unos 17 nombres (algunos sin reconocimiento en el DLE ni el DAMER) del **pavo**:

1. Pavo
2. guajolote
3. pavipollo
4. chompimpe
5. [totol](http://www.milenio.com/estilo/diez-cosas-que-no-sabias-sobre-los-pavos)
6. [güilo](https://www.elsiglodedurango.com.mx/noticia/244046.pavo-guajolote-totole-pipilo-o-cocono-ahora-y-siempre.html)
7. [tolote](https://www.elsiglodedurango.com.mx/noticia/244046.pavo-guajolote-totole-pipilo-o-cocono-ahora-y-siempre.html) <sub>(mismo enlace)</sub>
8. [cócono](https://www.elsiglodedurango.com.mx/noticia/244046.pavo-guajolote-totole-pipilo-o-cocono-ahora-y-siempre.html) <sub>(mismo enlace)</sub>
9. choncho
10. chumpipe
11. gallo de la tierra
12. gallo de papada
13. pípila
14. totollín
15. guanajo
16. [bimbo](http://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/MAM-720017)
17. [pisco](http://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/MAM-720017) <sub>(mismo enlace)</sub>

Comment: Entre familia también se le decía "gorda gorda gorda" (por onomatopeya en lo que dice el guajolote).