# ¿Cuál es la planta con más nombres en español?

Tags: sustantivos, sinónimos, plantas

Recordaba la pregunta del animal con [más nombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26397/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-animal-con-m%C3%A1s-nombres-en-castellano/) y leyendo hoy un artículo del maíz, me preguntaba si era esta la planta con más nombres en español. El problema es que en ocasiones un mismo nombre vulgar cobija diferentes plantas (por ejemplo, hay 4 árboles llamados [zapote](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapote) en Centroamérica y otro al norte de Suramérica).

Pero citando al maíz tenemos (incluyendo el *original*) 13 nombres:

- millo (Canarias y Salamanca)
- mijo (España)
- borona (España)
- panizo (España)
- elote (Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, CR, Ec)
- jojoto (Co, Ve)
- choclo (Co, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch, Py, Ar, Ur)
- chócolo (Co, Pe)
- mazorca
- sara (Pe, Bo)
- abatí  (Ar)
- avatí (Ar)

Otros tantos nombres no los encuentro en el DLE o en el DAMER, además de no ver nombres de las Antillas, de Chile, Paraguay o Uruguay.

¿Existe una planta con más nombres comunes (mejor si estos están en el DLE o en el Diccionario de americanismos)? ¿Qué otros nombres tiene el maíz que haya obviado en la pregunta?

Comment: Wow! // But I think you forgot *milpa (Mx)*.  Note, *elote* is only for sweet corn (tierno), not for the dry grain that you grind up.

Comment: milpa is not maíz, but an agricultural system that uses the same field to plant different crops at the same time

also, as aparente001 said, in México, mazorca and elote refers to the same plant in different times: fresh -> elote, dry -> mazorca

Comment: Dices que no ves nombres de Chile, Paraguay y Uruguay, y tu mismo los pusiste: "choclo (Co, Ec, Pe, Bo, **Ch**, **Py**, Ar, **Ur**)" la **Ch** es de Chile, **Py** de paraguay, **Ur** de Uruguay.

Comment: Es díficil de determinar. Al fin y al cabo, los dialectos llegan a ser casi infinitivos y en cada uno de ellos puede originarse una palabra diferente. Lo mismo sería interesante acotar un poco la pregunta a términos usados mayoritariamente en un país, o similar. Eso también permitiría poder buscar la respuesta algorítmicamente, mediante búsqueda en los diccionarios.